# BaseAdapter is not showing all data

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

I am populating a `ListView` using `BaseAdapter`. My array have two values, i'm getting size = 2 still list view is showing only one item. What is wrong with following code :

```
public class ActivityContactDetailScreen extends Activity{

String contact_id = "",nickName="",fname="",lname="",   
ArrayList<String> phone_number,email_id;
private ContactDataSource datasource;
long _id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_detail_screen);

    // open database connection
    datasource = new ContactDataSource(ActivityContactDetailScreen.this);
    datasource.open();

    // Get all required details from previous activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    contact_id = intent.getStringExtra("contact_id");   
    _id = intent.getLongExtra("_id", -1);

    Log.e("contact_id ",contact_id);

    String contactSql = "SELECT * FROM "
                    + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_CONTACT 
                    +" WHERE "
                    + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CNT_CONTACT_ID                                  
                    + " = "
                    + contact_id 
                    + " LIMIT 1";

    String phoneSql = "SELECT * FROM "
                    + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_PHONE
                    +" WHERE "
                    + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PHN_CONTACT_ID                                  
                    + " = "
                    + contact_id;       


    //Log.e("SQL ",contactSql +"::"+ phoneSql);

    MySQLiteHelper dbhelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this) ;
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    phone_number = new ArrayList<String>();             

    Cursor contact = database.rawQuery(contactSql, null);

    while(contact.moveToNext()){

            nickName = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CNT_NICK_NAME));
            fname =  contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CNT_FIRST_NAME));
            lname =  contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CNT_LAST_NAME));


            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.personal_info);
            TextView fnameTv = new TextView(ActivityContactDetailScreen.this);
            fnameTv.setText(fname +" : "+ lname);
            fnameTv.setPadding(20,0,0, 0);      
            linearLayout.addView(fnameTv);          

            Cursor phoneCrsr = database.rawQuery(phoneSql, null);                   
            while(phoneCrsr.moveToNext()){

                String number = phoneCrsr.getString(phoneCrsr.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PHN_NUMBER));                    
                if(!number.isEmpty()){
                    phone_number.add(number);                       
                }                   
            }               
            LinearLayout phoneLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.phone_info);
            phoneLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ListView phone_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_phone_number);
            phone_list.setAdapter(new showPhoneNumberAdapter(this)); 
            Log.e("PHONE DETAIL:",phone_number.toString());
            phoneCrsr.close();          

            for(int i = 0; i<contact.getColumnCount();i++){
                Log.e("CONTACT DETAIL:",""+ contact.getString(i));
            }
            Log.e("CONTACT DETAIL END:", "-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
        contact.close();
        database.close();

        // To set title of activity
        setTitle(nickName);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    datasource.close();
}

// Adapter to show phone numbers
    class showPhoneNumberAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public showPhoneNumberAdapter(Context context){
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }               
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            return phone_number.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertedView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertedView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_contact_detail_phonelist, parent, false);         

            TextView tv_number = (TextView)  convertedView.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            tv_number.setText(phone_number.get(position));          

            Log.e("getView:",":"+phone_number.get(position) +"::"+position);
            return convertedView;
        }   
    }
```

}

Comment: Is your ListView rendered in a ScrollView?

Comment: Make getItem() return value null to phone_number.get(arg0)

Comment: @SujithPt : Yes there is main scrollview->Relative Layot-> Liner Layout-> Listview.

Comment: @I-droid why dont you people use a SimpleCursorAdapter, its a third guy today that uses BaseAdapter to show sqlite db content...

Comment: @pskink : I'm fetching data using `rawquery`. I don't know how to use it with SimpleCursorAdapter. I will use it if you tell me how.

Comment: @I-droid see http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please call this method after adapter set to listview.This method calculate total height of listview and set it so you have no need to remove Scrollview.

```
public static void getTotalHeightofListView(ListView listView) {

ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

int totalHeight = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

    mView.measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
    Log.w("HEIGHT" + i, String.valueOf(totalHeight));

}

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight
        + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
listView.setLayoutParams(params);
listView.requestLayout();
```

}

Comment: lol, this code has no sense ... it is not ListView anymore `You've just recreated a very expensive LinearLayout :) –  Romain Guy(android team)`

Comment: @Selvin Ya it's right. But at some time when our overall layout's is very much big then we want to manage listview in ScrollView at that time only this one option for us.

Comment: moving mView outside the loop will help a little bit, but really scrolview inside scrolview it is a bad idea

Comment: @Kalpesh : I have a `imagebutton` in this listview. Using above method i'm unable to get click event of onItemClicked for listview. why?

Answer (score 0):

Updating your layout structure by removing the `ScrollView` will fix your issue.

**Or** you can use resized `ListView` based on the contents to fit it in the `ScrollView`.

```
// Resizing ListView based on contents
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: I would have not used that scrollview, but my layout can have longer content then screen size. So it become necessary to use it.

Comment: Then the you can choose the second option.

Comment: can second option stop my listview's item getting click events ??